# Layout for 8" android tablet

Tags: android, android-layout

I develop app for android. I test it on many devices but I have problem with 8" tablet with 800x600 resolution. The text field is out of the screen. I have 4 folders with layouts: "layout", "layout-small", "layout-large", "layout-xlarge". How can I make proper layout for this tablet?

Comment: check about multiple screen support available at Android Developers website.

Comment: is layout-large is not working?

Comment: No layout-large is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make four layout folders, one for each size bucket.  Put static text in each layout that says which one it is.  Run the app.  Read what gets displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Refer [Using new size qualifiers](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#NewQualifiers), where we have more control over the screen sizes.
We can set Qualifier values like `sw600dp`, `w800dp`, etc